# Is Unit test Required

Tags: asp.net, .net, unit-testing

I am developing a web portal in asp.net 3.5 which is mainly a front end for various other links and web forms developed else where. There is not much business logic except some CRUD operations to the database and fetching data. And javascript, Jquery for user interface.

In this scenario, is unit test necessary and is it required to test the javascript also?

Comment: unit testing is never necessary itself. But it can raise the maintenability and lower the potential number of bugs. Put into the equation the expected effort to make unit tests versus the expected effort to make the application evolves and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unittesting is not required to get something going, but as you start testing I hope that you see that it is crucial for maintaining a large code base.

Right now your app is small, and a user can easily verify that it is working.  ie. Go to a page, submit a form, make sure that the form is posting correctly, make sure that the database is saving the correct information.

As your application grows, or as you begin to build on your CRUD operations it will be crucial that they are correct and that you can test them programatically, testing your code now sounds like it would be trivial, and therefore with the effort, because of the time it saves in the future in regards to refactoring your code or hunting down bugs.

Qunit is a great simple javascript testing framework http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit

Answer (score 0):

Unit test is about reducing bug and speed up development.
It can also help refactoring your code.

If you have a small project and need to go to market fast and it will have a small amount of maintenance you can avoid unit testing.

If you have only simple CRUD operations consider use scaffolding tools and simple datasource/detail view and/or Dynamic Data.

Answer (score 0):

"Not much" business logic tends to grow over time. By writing unit tests to ensure that the business logic works, you'll be able to ensure it's not broken in the future, as you add more features. Unit testing also makes you write loosely-coupled code, which can have the advantageous side effect of making your code cleaner and more maintainable to begin with.

If you have a lot of jQuery and user interface operations, you can still write tests for those. For UI, look at [Coded UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx) or [WatiN](http://watin.org/). For JavaScript/jQuery, look at [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit).